# Как получить информацию о треке запущенного в системе

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net, .net-core

Мне нужно получить информацию о треке, который запущен в каком-либо внешнем плеере, необходимо получить его название и автора для программы на .Net C#. На скриншоте изображен пример того, что название трека и автор отображаются в системе, но необходимо как-то получить название и автора в программе на C#.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы нашли правильный код, его надо лишь правильно применить под конкретную платформу. Для понимания того, что требуется, и почему так, достаточно почитать [официальную документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance), где нас интересует два пункта в самом начале:

- Начиная с .NET 6 вы можете указать моникер целевой платформы (TFM) в файл проекта для получения доступа к API-интерфейсам WinRT. Этот вариант поддерживается в проектах, предназначенных для Windows 10 версии 1809 или более поздней.
- Для более ранних версий .NET можно установить пакет NuGet Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, чтобы добавить все необходимые ссылки в проект. Этот параметр поддерживается в проектах, предназначенных для Windows 10 версии 1803 или более поздней.

Другими словами, если ваш проект `.NET6` и выше, то в нем уже есть все необходимое для получения нужной информации, вам надо лишь указать правильно целевую платформу, под которую пишется ваш проект. Если ваш проект ниже `.NET6`, то вам нужно дополнительно установить пакет `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` из NuGet.

С пакетом все просто, а вот с целевой платформой могут наверно возникнуть проблемы, из-за чего я покажу пример на консольном приложении .NET7.

1. В студии жму два раза по названию моего проекта, открывается редактор `.csproj` файла, внутренности которого выглядят примерно так:

   ```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp_net</RootNamespace>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
   ```
2. В этом файле нас интересует значение `TargetFramework`, нам надо явно указать платформу. В документации есть нужные примеры:

   - net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 — если приложение предназначено для Windows 10, версия 1809.
   - net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0 — если приложение предназначено для Windows 10, версия 1903.
   - net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 — если приложение предназначено для Windows 10, версия 2004.
   - net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0 — если приложение предназначено для Windows 11.

   У меня .NET7, и приложение под Windows 11, значит я указываю `net7.0-windows10.0.22000.0`, если мне нужна была поддержка старой версии Windows, то я могу указать без проблем более старую версию из указанного списка, работать будет.
3. Указав целевую платформу, студия начнет восстанавливать все нужные пакеты, а в разделе "Зависимости" появится `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref`, который и будет отвечать на нужный функционал. Все, мы готовы писать код.

Код из вопроса именно то, что вам и нужно, я его немного сокращу, получу такое:

```
var mediaTramsportManager = await GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync();
var mediaSession = mediaTramsportManager.GetCurrentSession();
var mediaProperties = await mediaSession.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync();

Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", mediaProperties.Artist, mediaProperties.Title);
```

То есть, мы получаем нужную медиа сессию, из которой выдергиваем нужную нам информацию (автора, название, альбом, и даже обложку), а также, имея сессию, мы можем управлять медиа элементом (переключать треки, останавливать/возобновлять воспроизведение, и многое другое).

Вот и все, что нужно знать для получения подобной информации. Повторю, если проект старый (ниже .NET6), то нужно установить NuGet пакет `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts`. Удачи!

Comment: 3 раза про установку пакета - перебор, может подсократить чутка? :) но ответ шикарный. Еще про 7 и 6 перемешано, сбивает с толку, хотя понятно, что в данном контексте разницы никакой.

Comment: @aepot Моей целью было сделать так, чтоб читающий прям 100% уловил суть, где на старых версиях нужен дополнительно пакет, а на новых он ставиться самостоятельно. Сможете оставить этот посыл, но убрав лишнее упоминание, можете подправить, я не против. Что касается 6 и 7 - данная "фишка" появилась с 6 версии, и я просто копировал документацию, которая делает на это акцент, ну а 7 версия, я так показал тот факт, что на следующих версиях все будет аналогично, лишь измени цифру, а то будут спрашивать "а если у меня .NET99, что я должен писать?". Так что, разные версии я бы не убирал.